# Animated SVGs don't start until page is fully loaded

Tags: jquery, animation, svg, ads

My site contains quite a lot of ads, and these take a while to load. This isn't a problem exactly, but I've noticed any SVG animations will draw the first frame instantly, but the animation comes only after all the loading has completed on the page. The SVG animations usually indicate a spinner/loading icon. It doesn't really serve any purpose if it doesn't animate before the element it represents is loaded.

Is there a method to start the animation earlier?